# need direct3d model import example

Tags: model, 3d, load, directx, direct3d

Can someone point me to an example for loading a 3d model into a direct3d(9) scene?
I just want to be able to see the 3d model in my window.
Also, is there a 3d format that I can use that will already contain the surface coloring for me?

thanks

Comment: I'm not a Direct3D expert, but doesn't Direct3D have its own mesh file format (.x) that can be loaded by API functions? Otherwise, what 3d file format are you interested in?

Comment: I really haven't done a lot with d3d but I got a .dmc file that I think ties together several .obj and .png files and I'd love to make the character model into a desktop gadget.

Comment: Ok, .obj is a quite easy to read format. If you understand a bit of 3d grahpics and mesh data structures you should be able to write a simple importer. If not, then you should first learn some basics about direct3D and 3d graphics in general before attempting such things.

Comment: I'm familiar with obj format and have even written them by hand before but I fear not being able to take advantage of all the nice surface textures (UV style) that come with the model.

Comment: If it uses .obj it should use a corresponding .mtl for the materials and these again should reference the .png files. Handling the wavefront material format is equally easy (as long as you concentrate on the features you can easily reproduce with simple direct3d equivalents).

Answer (score 2):

Theres a samples directory that comes with your direct x SDK install. Look there.